# Как реализовать автоматический перенос блоков на след.строку при сужении экрана?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть квадратные блоки внутри бустраповского контейнера:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы они были в одной строке, а при сужении экрана переносились на след.строку по одному по мере сужения экрана? Без js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант задать контейнеру свойство: display: flex;
Почитать можно здесь про флексбоксы https://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.container .card_item{width: 150px;height:150px;background:#d3d3d3;border:1px solid red;}
.container{display:flex;flex-direction:row;flex-wrap:wrap;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
  <div class="card_item"></div>
</div>
```

Ко всему использовать медиазапросы:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
    // изменяем поведении  при этом расширении
}
```